# Understanding External Jars in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath

So I'm fairly new to Java and especially Eclipse, so please excuse my ignorance.  I took a project from a server and copied it locally to my machine.  When I opened the workspace, I had many errors due to it not being able to find the jars.  This makes sense because I don't have the same dir structure as the server I copied from.  So if I copy the same external jar's to my machine and get it to compile into a jar and copy it back to the server, will it work?  Or will it fail because now the external jar's are in a different place than it is expecting?

Also, down the road should I put the external jars into regular jars to avoid this problem?

Comment: So after more research it looks like they are using User Libraries, which contain the external JARs.  Can I change the path of the User Library's Jars to point to my local copies, if so how, and then would I be able to copy my executable JAR back to server without having to change anything else?  Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 2):

You should be OK. Java is using what is called classpath to locate dependencies. The classpath may be different on the development machines, but as long as all the dependencies are on the classpath in the production everything should work.

To avoid issues with the synchronisation of directory structures the most common way is to use Maven - it will manage all the dependencies for you (but you have to manage the pom.xml - the Maven's project descriptor). A little clumsier way is to have the dependencies in the project, however you may end up with many projects having to include same jars, and then there will be version conflicts and so on.

For small projects you can manage dependencies yourself, however larger projects will need a more thought through strategy (like Maven).

In regard to the executable jars, make sure the Class-Path entry in <jarfile>:\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF is correct, e.g. where it references other jars, those jars are going to be there in the production. For example, assume we have `ourjar.jar` and assume this is a snippet from its MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: lib/myteamjar.jar
```

It will then be expected that a following directory structure is in place:

```
lib/myteamjar.jar
ourjar.jar
```

Comment: THanks for your response.  I posted above more information.  I will definitely look at Maven in the future, sounds like a helpful tool but right now I'm pressed for time.

Comment: I have added some more information to my answer above. I suggest you change the user library path, generate your jar file, check that the manifest is correct. Then you'll be sure.

Comment: When I look at the manifest.mf for the current JAR, it doesn't have a class path entry, it just says: Manifest-Version: 1.0

Comment: If version is all it has, it's not strictly speaking an "executable" jar. Executable jars manifest needs to have Main-Class attribute, so that then you could execute it as simply as `java -jar myjar.jar` - it instructs Java where to look for the main() method. Given you don't have a class-path attribute, your classpath is given upon the execution, so not set in stone, probably like this: `java -cp lib/myteamjar.jar:ourjar.jar our.team.package.Main`

Comment: Looks like the jar is used by another program,and is not executable as you said.  So I should be able to just copy it from one location to another I'm hoping. I will try it out and let you know.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, the location of the external jars does not mater. What you want to do is put the external jars on your classpath. How you do it depends on how you are running your java code. If you are running it from the CLI using the `java` command, it takes the classpath as an argument. If you want your code to build/run in Eclipse, you need to right click on your project, select "Build Path" > "Configure Build Path..." Use the "Add JARs..." button to add jars that are part of a project you have open and "Add External JARs..." to add jars that reside outside of the project. See specific documentation for your tool for more details about classpaths.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend Maven to somebody who is fairly new to Java and Eclipse.  I would forget about Eclipse, too.

You have a packaging and CLASSPATH issue.  Focus on that.

What kind of project are you talking about?  The answer you get will depend on what type of app you're creating.  Is it an executable JAR?  Then the right way to do it is to package everything into a ZIP file that's laid out exactly as the CLASSPATH in the JAR manifest expects.

If it's a web app, the right thing is a WAR file, with all the JARs your app needs in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

If you package things properly, you should end up with a single package that has everything laid out the right way.  You should be able to deploy it to the server and make it all work.

Comment: It's a executable JAR.  I posted above it's using User Libraries that contain the external JARs, which it can't find since they are in a different location.  If I recreated (or change the path) of the user library on my machine and create the executable JAR it sounds like it might work when I copy it back to the original server?

Comment: You have to package the 3rd party JARs along with yours and deploy them on the server.  My recommendation would be to put all of them into a single directory, ZIP that up, and make the classpath point to the directory that they all live in.  Set up a script that runs the JAR and sets the CLASSPATH and you'll have no problems.